# RSA Encryption/Decryption Issue: Encrypted Text from .Net not decrypting in Java

Tags: java, .net, rsa, encryption

I am facing issues in decryption in Java. Following is the error encountered:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Blocktype mismatch: -127
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:311)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:255)
```

The text is encrypted in .Net with the following code:

```
public string EncryptString( string inputString, int dwKeySize, string xmlString )
        {
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider( dwKeySize );
            rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString( xmlString );
            int keySize = dwKeySize / 8;
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes( inputString );
            int maxLength = keySize - 42;
            int dataLength = bytes.Length;
            int iterations = dataLength / maxLength;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for( int i = 0; i <= iterations; i++ )
            {
                byte[] tempBytes = new byte[ ( dataLength - maxLength * i > maxLength ) ? maxLength : dataLength - maxLength * i ];
                Buffer.BlockCopy( bytes, maxLength * i, tempBytes, 0, tempBytes.Length );
                byte[] encryptedBytes = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt( tempBytes, true );

                Array.Reverse( encryptedBytes );
                stringBuilder.Append( Convert.ToBase64String( encryptedBytes ) );               
            }           
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

The code for decrytion is JAVA is:

```
PrivateKey privKey = readPrivateKey(); // reads the private key 
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
            byte[] encryptedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedText.getBytes("UTF-32"));
        encryptedBytes = reverse(b); // reverse the bytes 
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
        return new String(decrypted);
```

Am I missing something here? How can I make both way encryption/decryption?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This may help:

http://jafetsanchez.com/post/7562162652/rijndael-on-c-and-java

Comment: That appears to be a broken link now.

Answer (score 0):

Your C# application is using OAEP padding PKSC v2  while java is using PKSC v1.5 Try changing your C# code to:

```
ptedBytes = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt( tempBytes, false );
```

Comment: I changed the code as you mention but still I am not getting the right output. If the text is "ABC", I am getting the decrypted string as "A(3 unknown characters)B(3 unknown characters)C(3 unknown characters)". Am I missing something here?