# How to encrypt data with RSA in .Net Core and decrypt it in Java?

Tags: java, c#, asynchronous, encryption, public-key-encryption

I want to encrypt a string in c#(server/.Net Core) and decrypt it in java(client) using RSA and public/private keys. C# side has both private and public keys and the Java side should encrypt and decrypt with the public key.

These are Keys:

```
static string  privateKey = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>cBO/qYQLb376JT2QuPRnTi7Q24tgsZmg12TGGzYebXQtOH8+FDmBhkcMUt9+oLT7H5pKZKI8ql7eVKbK7rY7OAKBQd4g6BRG+09npObRX4zInZjRsqr6wzCcAul5ml+qVw765NRFlsVXzd5cYDp9+aTk=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>2lTMG9Kxa1IH/Heo/eiYVb+7+lY3Lp+PcQ6NG866mqPlgEeuh3dc2DjAqira665l+GS5X6rM775PSWIU+tCTow==</P><Q>2w235CmX9NPRSmeXFiERm3gDUjl7jPsA+ynZAEBuVD/UYZ/QfAtSwoW9puWbLos0W1YfKxmxcXRtZaGl5Mz9cw==</Q><DP>oVE8SmZ/rsM6oWEsnQbJ37m+Q7aGKU2955QP0PcLS41D2mecXf1kvWIZgOIPRUpjj4ekrDoAGDfuT1NIGxYXrw==</DP><DQ>2rq4BHwD39QiB8moc9BRZIxRxKjhVcTNFf6TUE0F3dpel5yc8T/dQ5+H4D8k1TTq8sjsFn1xUXiQRAtFO1H1QQ==</DQ><InverseQ>lW6iyrtSYGK0ehBMLPEGbHlu7e5TiBhVDPuQMKl5K7arQXlPevjPLYKkvxOWSak6GAjZJkj9tOEbqnQ3YGSFXA==</InverseQ><D>fSdbNllNf8iMcR1bfohxXN1cpqDDq6B5XDZAw64Jig2wt0cad4BYkqgbJpUx/6MTMzxSZs8qjfuiZYvvnl/wieGoOZWx78mjSLz5bl5QKcIjTUirUX1jzcguLZJXJnDpZQfjLui2e2l69b/5c62iEB0dSd7nHrvYYV4YQALLHgE=</D></RSAKeyValue>";//rsa1.ToXmlString(true);
static string  publicKey = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>cBO/qYQLb376JT2QuPRnTi7Q24tgsZmg12TGGzYebXQtOH8+FDmBhkcMUt9+oLT7H5pKZKI8ql7eVKbK7rY7OAKBQd4g6BRG+09npObRX4zInZjRsqr6wzCcAul5ml+qVw765NRFlsVXzd5cYDp9+aTk=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";
```

Encryption Method in c#:

```
 static string Encrypt(string text)
    {
        const int PROVIDER_RSA_FULL = 1;
        const string CONTAINER_NAME = "Tracker";

        CspParameters cspParams;
        cspParams = new CspParameters(PROVIDER_RSA_FULL);
        cspParams.KeyContainerName = CONTAINER_NAME;
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa1 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
        rsa1.FromXmlString(publicKey);

        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] textBytes = encoding.GetBytes(text);
        byte[] encryptedOutput = rsa1.Encrypt(textBytes, false);
       // byte[] encryptedOutput = rsa1.Encrypt(textBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);
        string outputB64 = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedOutput);

        return outputB64;
    }
```

The output of encryption method in c# (test data was: "123"):

```
 static String mydata="AynqFwY2BMb7q6DXEOPiFSmqTjt3k+yRmkhU2QyEGoVR8SzcenUec0PFWERLAZmarq/Gxp7gJSf1MNHyTQRjTPaMqao5PXHb+Cl7p+CiXtt2hSPZesRI7APGOYhN6Zvmu+uIDEqdbcpfrXuY+4kY8eFnWZ+rnX/FXm5cHEMrnxQ=";
```

Decryption Method in Java:

```
   static String Decrypt(String encodedString) {
    try {
        byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKey);
        byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode("AQAB");
        BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);
        BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes);

        RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPubKey = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(rsaPubKey);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

        byte[] cipherData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString);
        byte[] plainBytes = cipher.doFinal(cipherData);
        return new String(plainBytes, "UTF-8");

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchPaddingException | UnsupportedEncodingException | InvalidKeyException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException err) {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }
    return "Error";
}
```

It seems the problem is in this line in java function:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding);
```

I set true and false in c# function in this line but doesn't work:

```
byte[] encryptedOutput = rsa1.Encrypt(textBytes, false);
```

after that deceided to replace it with:

```
byte[] encryptedOutput = rsa1.Encrypt(textBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);
```

Did not work, and tested all the padding types in both functions and check all but didn't work.

I checked solutions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676406/rsa-encryption-decryption-issue-encrypted-text-from-net-not-decrypting-in-java) but I think the problem is not about padding maybe its because of encode and decode the strings.

Comment: Have you tried `rsa.Encrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1)`? Also I hope this doesn't need to be said, but if these are real keys you will need to change them now.

Comment: @AustinG Yes I did, put it on my c# function and in java:"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", The error is: "javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error"

Comment: Private/Public key cryptography (encryption) works with different keys. For the encryption part you have to use the PUBLIC key and on the decryption side it is the PRIVATE key that's in use.